# Bitwise right shift PHP x32 and x64

Tags: php

I'm trying to use bitwise right shift on my local machine and server. And the results are different. I use this test on both PHP:

```
$sourceInt = 1391343920825;
$resultInt = $sourceInt >> 3;
$resultInt32 = $resultInt & 0xffffffff; // Here I'm trying to cut all bits older than 32

echo "TEST:<br>";
echo "x64: " . $resultInt;
echo "<br>x32: " . $resultInt32;

$binSource = unpack ( "C*", pack ( "L", $sourceInt ) );
$binInt = unpack ( "C*", pack ( "L", $resultInt ) );
$binInt32 = unpack ( "C*", pack ( "L", $resultInt32 ) );

echo "<br>Binaries:<br>Source bin: ";
var_dump ( $binSource );
echo "<br>x64 bin: ";
var_dump ( $binInt );
echo "<br>x32 bin: ";
var_dump ( $binInt32 );
```

What I have on local machine (PHP 5.3 x32):

```
TEST:
x64: -28185385
x32: -28185385
Binaries:
Source bin: array(4) { [1]=> int(185) [2]=> int(102) [3]=> int(143) [4]=> int(242) } 
x64 bin: array(4) { [1]=> int(215) [2]=> int(236) [3]=> int(81) [4]=> int(254) } 
x32 bin: array(4) { [1]=> int(215) [2]=> int(236) [3]=> int(81) [4]=> int(254) }
```

And on server (PHP 5.3 x64):

```
TEST:
x64: 173917990103
x32: 2119298263
Binaries:
Source bin: array(4) { [1]=> int(185) [2]=> int(102) [3]=> int(143) [4]=> int(242) } 
x64 bin: array(4) { [1]=> int(215) [2]=> int(236) [3]=> int(81) [4]=> int(126) } 
x32 bin: array(4) { [1]=> int(215) [2]=> int(236) [3]=> int(81) [4]=> int(126) }
```

Whats wrong guys? I don't have any idea.

P.S. It seem that server is x32 too, because Integer stored only in 4 bytes instead of 8.

Answer (score 0):

A 32-bit integer can only store a value up to 2,147,483,647 (2<sup>31</sup>-1).

According to the [PHP manual's "Integers"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php):

> The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18.

To perform math exceeding native capabilities in PHP, try using the [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) extension.

Comment: I saw GMP extension, but didn't find any bitwise right/left shift operation. So how can I use it in my case? Can you show me, please, an example?

Comment: Oh, I found an answer: to shift left, just multiply the number by pow(2,x), and to shift right, divide by pow(2,x).
Thank you for your solution, I'll try to use it right now =)

Comment: When I'm using GMP ext it returns wrong result too: 173917990103.